# How would a galactic scale industry affect local industry or global industry?

Tags: economy, far-future, business

The setting that I am asking about is a massive almost galaxy-spanning country that has an industrial chokehold on all the other nations around it. However, large-scale industry in this setting primarily sells products to other large-scale industries or governmental structures. these "large industries" could (and do) easily use entire planets for resources or as giant factories. What I am asking is how this itself and external economic shifts would affect a smaller sub-urban world. Earth is a good example of a medium-population planet, that is not very urbanized and thus a sub-urban planet. So how would local business be anywhere between the store down the street kind of thing to a mega-corporation that has grasps globally, since both are technically local businesses?

Secondarily this society has massive incentives to have a #2 business as the best companies are usually taken control of by the government, or have deep political connections to the ancient religion that permeates their culture. (their culture is realistically pretty similar to Western society)

I'm not sure how feasible it is to answer this question so I have provided some answers I thought of myself that may or may not make sense:

1. Local businesses interact by buying supplies from galaxy size companies however greater economic shifts don't impact local communities all that much.
2. Local businesses don't exist outside of rural or are expensive to ship to locations due to the total economic stronghold that the major companies have. (I'm not too sure about this)

I'm not certain that I am conveying my confusion but hopefully, I can get a couple of answers that should help me figure out the dynamic between local and large businesses.

Comment: Please clarify the speed and expense of interstellar communications and transport. This will greatly affect how the economy turns out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How a large industrial center would affect smaller industrial centers depends on (1) what does the large industrial center make, (2) what do the smaller industrial centers make, (3) the market prices of the things they make, (4) labor costs, (5) raw material costs, (6) where the raw materials come from, (7) how much does it cost to transport a tonne of goods from here to there, (8) how long does it take to transport a tonne of goods from here to there, (9) how perishable the goods are. None of these pieces of data are given in the question. Asking about economic effects without any data.

Comment: Oh, and the title of the question is about industry, and then the body of the question veers into retail. Making stuff, selling stuff to consumers, and running a large online shop are three completely different businesses. For a practical example, Amazon the gigantic American online shop and Dacia the Romanian automobile manufacturer are not in competition.

Comment: Assumption 1. Is sadly completely wrong if they buy from big suppliers they will of course be hit by big market developments as they are directly linked to them.

Comment: Assumption 2. Is more correct as local businesses would indeed probably take the place of big corporations if we assume said big corporations don't care about certain places. And yes where the megacorps conduct business there would be probably be a very limited number of local businesses or they would just be bought up by the big corporations. The only way they could survive is by offering unique services that big companies see as unprofitable though otherwise they have no chance competitive wise.

Comment: If make your question more clear i can give you a more detailed answer. What are you asking for at the moment is to basically create an complete Market economy out of your given conditions. Such a thing however is highly out of scope for a single question. Also it's generally really difficult to predict how a market works in its specifics as there are way to many variables so please limit what you want to know and i tell you how it would broadly function. Just don't expect an highly specific answer as economies are rather complex entities.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock Assumption 2. may actually be worse than assumption 1. in some ways, the only way a 'galactic' industrial supply chain (and the also required delivery to market) can possibly exist is if you have teleport gates ort really fast FTL, with that sort of transport speed available to you there is no "rural" backwaters excluded from the big markets, the whole galaxy becomes like east anglia, no one is more than half an hours drive to nearest town, the idea of there being the equivalent of rural backwoods that can't get to the big shops or big factories becomes a nonsense.

Comment: Yes i also thought about that. I just assumed that hey maybe there are some places megacorps just care about like a backwater planet. Which could then develop it's own local economy which would probably be not competitive outside it's bubble. But yes such future technology could very well eliminate back water places as we know them.

Comment: Close voters may be jumping the gun a little, this is a new user, at least give him a day or two to digest the feedback and potentially revise the question .. OP you might find [taking the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) may help suggest to you how you might hone your question a little.

Comment: Yes i also think that us the best option. I will be watching this question closely to give an answer once it has been made a little more clear what it's author wants.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's open-ended, hypothetical, opinion-based, and violates the book rule... all of which are prophibited in the [help]. This might have been answerable on the basis of globalization vs. local economies if you'd described the business structures and dependencies well enough. But it might be easier to describe what [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609) you want ans asking us to help rationalize that.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming relatively easy communications and transport:*

Not much different from the competition between local, national, and international business today. If barriers to trade and transport are low, the principle of [comparative advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_advantage) means that stuff gets imported and exported.

Say planet A has many good microchip factories. They produce at scale, specialists are available for repairs, engineering students at university get exam problems from this area and not others. *It takes 0.1 man-hours to produce a microchip.* Smartphone housings are produced in great numbers by advanced 3D printing. *It takes 0.01 man-hours to produce a housing.*

For simplicity, assume that those are the only parts which go into a smartphone.

Planet B is less developed overall, and especially less developed when it comes to microchips. Their fabs have a higher rejection rate, and when something goes really wrong the fab stands idle while they wait for foreign experts. *It takes 1 man-hour to produce a microchip*. They also produce smartphone housings by stamping metal, molding plastics, and joining them. *It takes 0.5 man-hours to produce one housing.*

So what does that mean?

- Per 8-hour working day, a worker on planet A could produce 72.7 smartphones.
- Per 8-hour working day, a worker on planet B could produce 5.33 smartphones.
- Per 8-hour working day, a worker in planet A and a worker on planet B could produce 87.3 smartphones (16 housings on B, 87.3 microchips and 71.3 housings on B).

So it pays for the workers on A to outsource the production of casings to B, *even if they could make them cheaper with their advanced technology than B.* Planet A concentrates on doing what they do **'more better'** and import what they do **'less better'**.

Just wgo reaps the benefit of interstellar trade remains to be decided in your setting. The workers on A? The workers on B? The workers on both planets? The interstellar megacorp on C which organizes the trade?

There are more than two parts which go into a smartphone, so a large, interstellar corporation with offices on many planets might have better chances to watch trends and to find the cheapest suppliers for their supply chain. If travel is cheap enough, parts from dozens of high-tech and mid-tech planets may be shipped to low-tech worlds for assembly and packaging, and then back for sale.

But where the market is too small for the big players (*"what, you need 10k units? Sorry, we only sell by the million!"*) a small company might thrive. Hire a *'space trucker'* to fly to planet D, get *half* a container of smartphones from a wholesaler, detour to planet E for a *quarter* container of frozen fish and to planet F for a *quarter* container of raincoats, and they might make a little profit.

Comment: About the last part i think they may still be depend on the bigger corporations. Like for example a planets corporation would likely buy from a galactic company. The planetary company could then sell to local super markets. But would be dependent on the galactic company and if they have something against you and don't sell you specific goods they could really strangle a single planets economy though how much they could do so depends probably on how much competition a galactic company has.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock, I was assuming an absence of monopolies and cartels. But *rely* may be the wrong term. It could be that the galactic company *manages to outcompete* the planetary company. If it ceases to do a specific business, it does not compete any more.

Comment: From my view it's likely that a planet does a high amount of outsourcing. Because why not the big corporations can provide way cheaper goods than local ones. This could be so extreme that the planet cannot support itself with basic things like food as it may be cheaply produced on planet size farms. And a big company would probably easily abuse this reliance to some extent though again how much of this is possible depends on their competitors. But a galactic scale nestle that controls almost the whole food industry would hold immense power.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock, that only works if there are are so-called entry barriers to the market. If the big companies abuse their power, *something* must stop a new company from offering a *slightly* better deal. In my example, planet B stops producing microchips because imports are cheaper. The will not be able to restart quickly.

Comment: I mean that is basically what i said isn't it. The only way a smaller company could be profitable is if they offer something a big company does not care about. Such things are often niche products or services.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock, or niche markets for mainstream products. Say the mid-size town has franchise fast food restaurants, the little town has a single diner, because there wouldn't be business for more.

Comment: Yes such things would be possible as a big company may not think it is profitable for them to open up a business like this in a small town. On the other side you could have small settlements that literally are to small for anyone to get a profit out of opening up a business. This could lead them to literally having no food available for them aw all smaller companies that once did fill this role were driven out of business.